# add custom logic using agora ui kit when an event occur - agora-react-uikit

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng, agora, agora-implementation

```
const rtcProps = {
    appId: appId,
    channel: streamId,
    token: null,
  };

 const callbacks = {
    EndCall: () => {
      router.replace("/");
    },
  };

  const rtmProps = {};

      <AgoraUIKit rtcProps={rtcProps} callbacks={callbacks} rtmProps={rtmProps} />`
```

i want to add custom logic when the user is joined. i am unable to identify a way in agora-react-uikit, altough there is a way if I use Agora web SDK but i want to use Agora ui kit.